# When do we say that a complex function is integrable?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definition

If $f$ is a real valued function on $[a,b]$,we say $f$ to be integrable if $L\int_{[a,b]} f=U\int_{[a,b]} f$ i.e if the upper and lower Riemann integrals coincide.But in any complex analysis book,we find the definition of integration of $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ along a curve in $\Omega$ to be $\int_{C} f(z)dz:=\int_{a}^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$ where $z$ is any parametrisation of $C$.Now my question is for what class of complex functions can we define this integration.Clearly,the integral on the RHS may not exist for every $f$,For continuous functions we have no problem.But are continuous functions the only class for which we can define these integrals?

Comment: A complex function is integrable iff its real and imaginary parts are both integrable.

Comment: @K.defaoite you are defining for a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ but I am looking for functions on complex domain and with complex image.

Comment: In this context integration in the complex plane is always done on one-dimensional subsets $S\subset \Bbb{C}$. So we can always translate integration of a function $f:S\to \Bbb{C}$ to a function $[a,b]\to\Bbb{C}$ by parameterizing $S$. 
Complex integration on *open* sets $\Omega\subseteq \Bbb{C}$ is a completely different beast and should only be tackled once you have a firm footing in measure theory.

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes I understand but what is the condition on $f$ so that the integral $\int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$ exists.

Comment: @K.defaoite Do we define it for $f$ continuous only?

Comment: No. $f:S\to\Bbb{C}$ is integrable if $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb{C}$ is integrable where $g(t)=f(z(t))z'(t)$.